# Get Access token with Azure AD multi-tenant openID authentication

Tags: authentication, azure, azure-active-directory

I followed the sample code [here](https://github.com/AzureADSamples/WebApp-MultiTenant-OpenIdConnect-DotNet) to create a MVC web app with Azure AD multi-tenant OpenID authentication. I use the following code to get user sign in.

```
public void SignIn()
{
    if (!Request.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = "/" }, OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
    }
}
```

Now I need to send a web api call which is protected by my Azure AD as well. Currently, before I send the request I use ADAL library to ask users to login again and get the access token like this.

```
AuthenticationContext ac = new AuthenticationContext(authority);
AuthenticationResult ar = ac.AcquireToken(resourceID, clientID, redirectURI, PromptBehavior.Always); 
string accessToken = ar.AccessToken;
```

However, since the authentication used in the MVC(if the user is from my AD) is the same as the one used to protect the web api. I'm wondering if there is a way to get the access token when user login with this openID authentication so that I can skip the second login with ADAL?

UPDATE:
Following vibronet's answer, I am trying to use the following code to get the token:

```
string authority = "https://login.windows.net/ucdavisprojecthotmail.onmicrosoft.com";

ClientCredential clientcred = new ClientCredential(clientId, appKey);
AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority);
AuthenticationResult result = authContext.AcquireTokenSilent(resourceID, clientcred, new UserIdentifier(userObjectID, UserIdentifierType.UniqueId));
```

Here, this code is used in an MVC web app and the clienId and appKey is the clientID and key of the web API I want to call. The resoureID is the APP ID URI of the web API obtained in Azure portal.

However, I got this error: Failed to acquire token silently. Call method AcquireToken. Anything I was missing?

Answer (score 2):

Absolutely. Check out https://github.com/AzureADSamples/WebApp-WebAPI-MultiTenant-OpenIdConnect-DotNet, it's like the sample you've been working with but with in addition the access token acquisition and use you are asking about. Also note, AcquireTokenSilent can only work if you have a token in the cache - to be used directly or refreshed. FInally: when you ask for a token, you must specify both the ID fo the resource you want a token for, and the clientID of the application doing the request. In your code, you appear to have used the clientID of the target app. Please refer to the sample I linked above, it shows the exact pattern to be used in this scenario.

Comment: After I checked the sample code you provided, I am aware that I need to use AcquireTokenSilent method. In the sample, the AuthenticationContext is constructed with a taken cache like this: `AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(string.Format("https://login.microsoftonline.com/{0}", tenantID), new EFADALTokenCache(signedInUserID));`. In the sample code it seems that I need to deal with the db. Let's assume that I don't need multi-tenant at all, I just need to use only my AD. Is there an simpler way to construct a token cache without interacting with db?

Comment: You can build a cache using any persistent layer you like. For example, see https://github.com/AzureADSamples/WebApp-WebAPI-OpenIDConnect-DotNet where the cache is saved in the session. The cache isn't really there for handling multitenancy, it is needed whenever you want to persist access tokens.

Comment: Can I get the token without this cache?

Comment: yes, but then you'll have to keep asking for it at every request

Comment: I tried with the AcquireTokenSilent but that doesn't work. I have updated the question. Please have a look. Thanks!

Comment: I edited my answer, but I am not sure if what we are doing is SO's best practice.

Comment: I think The MVC application that calls the API should be created as an native application on Azure portal, but there is no key for a native application on Azure portal. If I use client ID as the ID of the native application, what should use for the key?

Comment: The readme of the sample has complete instructions on how to set things up and what values go where. Did you have a chance to review it thoroughly?